# Azure Web App for Container can't connect to Azure DB for Postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql, azure, containers

I have a Azure Web App for Containers.  I am trying to get the web app to connect to a Azure Database for Postgres.

The web app gave me an error "OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"

From the portal, I have granted "Allow access to Azure services" and included all the IPs in the rules.

Is there anything I have missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

DO you add the connection string in the [Application settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure?toc=%2Fazure%2Fapp-service%2Fcontainers%2Ftoc.json)? Besides, regarding how to build a Python and PostgreSQL web app in Azure, please refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-python-postgresql-app).

Comment: The sample app works well with my azure postgres.  The app I have is using gunicorn.  Its workers are having trouble connecting :(

Comment: Hi. Is that you can run the application on your local?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add connection string (`VARNAME`) under Web App -> Configuration -> Connection Strings. Remember to use the variable like below in the code -

```
SQLServer: SQLCONNSTR_VARNAME
MySQL: MYSQLCONNSTR_VARNAME
SQLAzure: SQLAZURECONNSTR_VARNAME
Custom: CUSTOMCONNSTR_VARNAME
PostgreSQL: POSTGRESQLCONNSTR_VARNAME
```